# How do I setup a Dell 1135n Laser MFP?

Tags: printing, dell

Trying to setup Dell 1135n Laser MFP on Ubuntu 11.10

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosamsungspl failed
```

I copied the rastertosamsungspl from the DVD

```
/media/DELL_MFP/Linux/i386/at_root/usr/lib/cups/filter
```

to

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter
```

starting the process I add the Dell 1135n Laser MFP from the system settings and thats as far as I have been able to get.

Any help would be very appreciated!

- [Troubleshoot.txt](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/842344/)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not include a driver for this Dell printer.

A google search tells me that Dell's 1135N might actually be a rebadged Samsung SCX-4623F with customised firmware.

Can you try weather the splix driver for the Samsung SCX-4623F, which is included with Ubuntu, works with your printer? Go to system-config-printer (System -> Administration -> Printing in GNOME classic, Gear icon at the upper right of the screen -> Printers in Unity), right click your Printer and select Properties > click Change... next to the Make and Model field to see the available drivers and change it to Samsung SCX-4623F.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the driver from the Dell Website. 
http://ftp.dell.com/FOLDER00294749M/1/Dell1135n_Linux_v1.19.tar.gz
However I am not sure about the Ubuntu versions supported.